# Integrating iOS6 facebook function

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios6

I am trying to export a screen shot from my application to Facebook using the iOS6 Facebook function. How can I bring out the options inside the application when the button is pressed?

Below is my current code. I want to take the screenshot and at the same time export to Facebook using iOS6 Facebook function.

```
- (IBAction)export1:(id)sender{

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                              animated:YES];
exporting.hidden=YES;

CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);

else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
CGRect contentRectToCrop = CGRectMake(0, 70, 740, 740);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], contentRectToCrop);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: We can't tell you how because it's under the NDA yet.

Comment: But there might be some documentation or videos also under NDA that will. And there's the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: Understood. Thank you rickster and H2CO3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153307/how-to-do-facebook-login-in-ios-6/13153474#13153474) is how to post images to Facebook easily using the built in Facebook SDK in iOS6. Happy if this helps you in any ways. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Developer Site Gives a new Social.framework for integrating the Social Experiences like Twitter and Facebook.

Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Clarence i think you  should check out latest [Facebook SDK for iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/)

it also has some tutorials on how to post images on facebook in iOS 6.

Just download the SDK and you will find sample codes in your Documents folder which include a sample HelloFacebookSample which shows how to post image on facebook in iOS 6.

you just need to pass your image object in this method -

```
[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:nil image:croppedImage url:nil handler:nil];
```

before using above method you need to properly follow v 3.1 installation instructions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)